# Comparing one array element to multiple array elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have two text files that have data like this below: 
File A:

```
4,12-98-1,38.4611,APO,Tue,Jan,07,14:31:34,2014
5,12-111-1,0.9520,APO,Tue,Jan,07,11:56:21,2014,
6,12-176-1,8.0510,APO,Tue,Jan,07,11:58:10,2014,
7,12-214-1,165.2349,APO,Tue,Jan,07,14:33:19,2014
8,12-293-1,61.2558,APO,Tue,Jan,07,14:35:11,2014
9,12-805-1,2.0987,APO,Tue,Jan,07,12:03:30,2014,
10,12-986-1,3.7740,APO,Tue,Jan,07,12:05:16,2014,
```

File B:

```
4,12-98-1,43.6546,APO,Tue,Jan,07,10:26:32,2014,
5,12-111-1,1.0430,APO,Tue,Jan,07,10:28:18,2014,
6,12-176-1,13.5606,APO,Tue,Jan,07,10:30:04,2014,
7,12-214-1,44.7091,APO,Tue,Jan,07,10:35:27,2014,
8,12-293-1,44.3001,APO,Tue,Jan,07,10:37:14,2014,
10,12-805-1,2.6451,APO,Tue,Jan,07,10:39:01,2014,
```

Each of those lines are stored in an array. I want to compare the first array element of the first line of File A with all the first array elements of all the lines in File B and then the first array element of the second line of File A with all the first array elements of all the lines in File B and keep going.... till the end of the file.

I managed to get the ones that match while reading both text files. However I can`t get it to match for instance the last line on each file which first array element is 10 on both files.

How can I do that?

Here is what I have done:

```
 while ( (TKN24_line2 = TKN24br2.readLine()) != null && (TKN2_line2 = TKN2br2.readLine()) != null){
        TKN24_array2 = TKN24_line2.split(",");
        int b = 0;
        for(String s : TKN24_array2){
            //System.out.println("values[" + b + "] = " + s);
            b++;
        }

        TKN2_array2 = TKN2_line2.split(",");
        int c = 0;
        for(String s : TKN2_array2){
            //System.out.println("values[" + c + "] = " + s);
            c++;
        }

        if(TKN24_array2[0].contentEquals(TKN2_array2[0])){
            //Print something.
        }

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you compare the complete line using `String#equals()`? Why are you converting it into array? Store the complete data in memory if file size is very small and just compare it line by line.

Comment: The lines are not equal, they have different data. What would be equal is the first part which is a number. That`s why I converted them into arrays. @Braj

Comment: So you want it to compare on the basis of first number?

Comment: Yes, that`s right. @Braj

Comment: This reads pairs of lines from each file and compares only lines at the same position (line 1 with line 1, line 2 with line 2, etc.) It will stop as soon as either reader reaches end of file, which means it stops after the shorter of the two files.

Comment: Yes, I did realize that, but is there anyway to make it keep reading until it finds it even if the file ends? @DavidConrad

Comment: Of course. Just change your while loop. You'll need to have one loop for each file. But there are better ways to do it if all the data fits in memory.

Comment: Ok, Yes all the data should fit in memory the files are short. Could you guide me through to get started? @DavidConrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the data doesn't fit in memory, you will have to open and read the file B for every line of file A:

```
try (FileReader frA = new FileReader(filenameA);
    BufferedReader brA = new BufferedReader(frA)) {
    String lineA;
    while ((lineA = brA.readLine()) != null) {
        String value = lineA.split(",")[0];
        try (FileReader frB = new FileReader(filenameB);
            BufferedReader brB = new BufferedReader(frB)) {
            boolean found = false;
            String lineB;
            while ((lineB = brB.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = lineB.split(",");
                if (value.equals(values[0])) {
                    if (!found) {
                        System.out.println("Matches for " + value + ":");
                    }
                    System.out.println(lineB);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the data does fit in memory, then you could read all the lines into two lists, and then process the lists using nested loops, or you could put the lines of file B into a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) indexed by the value at the beginning of the line, and then look up the matching lines directly.

```
ListMultimap<String, String> fileB = ArrayListMultimap.create();
try (FileReader frB = new FileReader(filenameB);
    BufferedReader brB = new BufferedReader(frB)) {
    String lineB;
    while ((lineB = brB.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = lineB.split(",");
        fileB.put(values[0], lineB); // map from first value to full line
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try (FileReader frA = new FileReader(filenameA);
    BufferedReader brA = new BufferedReader(frA)) {
    String lineA;
    while ((lineA = brA.readLine()) != null) {
        String value = lineA.split(",")[0];
        if (fileB.containsKey(value)) {
            System.out.println("Matches for " + value + ":");
            for (String line : fileB.get(value)) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Very neat! Thanks a lot! @David Conrad